# Getting 'symbolize_keys' error in unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I have the following test:

```
test "vote for candidate" do
  get :vote, @candidate[:id]
  assert_equals(1, @candidate.votes.count)
end
```

Here is the method that I am trying to test:

```
def vote
  @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
  @candidate.votes.create
  redirect_to(candidates_path)
end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
CandidatesControllerTest#test_vote_for_candidate:
NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "358247726":String
test/controllers/candidates_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:CandidatesControllerTest>'
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be a great help.

Comment: What's in `@candidate`? In order for `@candidate[:id]` to be right, it has to be a `hash`.

Comment: @sebkomianos It looks like @candidate is an instance of an ActiveRecord model.  If I recall, ActiveRecord models do implement `#[]`.

Comment: @WayneConrad You are right, my bad! I ended up upvoting your comment and Simone's answer as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` method expect a Hash of params as seconda argument, you are passing a `String`. Change this line

```
get :vote, @candidate[:id]
```

into

```
get :vote, id: @candidate[:id]
```

or, assuming `@candidate` is an ActiveRecord object:

```
get :vote, id: @candidate.to_param
```